# How to read (with read()) an hex and print it on screen?

Tags: hex, printf

I want to read a file with some hexadecimals values. Such as this one :

```
^@\352\203\363
```

Or this when you put emacs in hexl-mode :

```
00ea 83f3
```

Here's a link to my file i'm trying to open :
http://www.partage-facile.com/0L9FOY7ERB/toto.cor.html

Now here's my main where I try to read and print it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
     int fd;
     char tmp[4];

     if ((fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
     {
        printf("Open failed.\n");
        return (-1);
     }
     if ((read(fd, tmp, 4)) == -1)
     {
        printf("Read failed.\n");
        return (-1);
     }
     printf("%s", tmp); /* Here I don't know really what to do to print. */
     if ((close(fd)) == -1)
     {
        printf("Close failed.\n");
        return (-1);
     }
     return (0);
}
```

But it print me nothing, just blank. And if I try to print with printf (with flags like %x for hex it does randoms values)

Comment: You need to tell us what you're getting, and what's going wrong.

Comment: It print me nothing, just blank.
And if I try to print with printf (with flags like %x for hex it does randoms values)

Comment: Okay, now turn that comment into a sentence, and edit your question so that it says this.

Comment: Is it because your code fails to compile?  I need `#include <fcntl.h>` for this to compile.  But when it does, it works.

Comment: Yes that was dumb of me, forgot one include for open(). But still doesn't work for me.
Well.. That work if i write manually "^@\352\203\363" but the one i got is written in red.
Here's a link to the file i'm opening.
http://www.partage-facile.com/0L9FOY7ERB/toto.cor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't print anything is that the first byte is null, which `printf("%s")` considers to mean "end of string".  And if there had been no null bytes in the data, `printf` wouldn't have known where to stop, causing an overrun.

What you have in `tmp` is *not* a C string, just an array of 4 bytes.  You can print them with something like this:

```
printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x", tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3]);
```

`%x` is the format specifier for hexadecimal integers, `2` is the field length and `0` means that the value should be zero-prefixed if it's shorter that the field length, i.e. the value `1` should be printed as `01` etc.